# Getting last of Multiple div in the same parent

Tags: css

I have been asked to get the span.vatText which has the text incl. VAT.

```
<ul class="products" data-role="listview" data-theme="d">
    <li class="product" data-productid="1504x2-Rung-Superior-Multi-Purpose-Ladder">
        <a href="/product/1504x2-Rung-Superior-Multi-Purpose-Ladder" class="hasThumb">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="http://www.blah.co.uk/acatalog/4x2.jpg" alt="blah" />
            </div>
            <h2 class="wrappable">Products name</h2>
            <p class="price">
                <span class="price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />
                    <span class="priceExclVat">
                        <span class="priceOriginal">&#163;133.32</span>
                        <strong class="priceSale">&#163;49.99</strong>
                        <span class="vatText">excl. VAT</span>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <span class="priceOriginal">&#163;159.99</span>
                        <strong class="priceSale" itemprop="price">&#163;59.99</strong>
                        <span class="vatText">incl. VAT</span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </p>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I have tried using the pseudo code such has nth-child and nth-of-type but these don't seem to work. I was just wondering how I can obtain just the last .vatText. Thank you for any help which you can provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `last-child` pseudo attribute to achieve what you are looking for.